# Minecraft Arrow Targets

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm Trying to make a door that opens when you shoot an arrow in the middle, but I can't find a way to add coordinates to the parameters. Is there a way? (the current ***working*** command is `/testfor @e[type=Arrow]` )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the basics of commands in Minecraft Java Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354614/what-are-the-basics-of-commands-in-minecraft-java-edition)

Comment: (target selectors and limiting them are one of the things covered by the answer to that question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the x, y, z and r parameters to search radius r from point xyz. These specific arguments can actually be compressed so long as they are in that order, so your command can look like this:

```
/testfor @e[x=10,y=64,z=10,r=1,type=Arrow]
```

Or this:

```
/testfor @e[10,64,10,1,type=Arrow]
```

You can also use dx, dy, and dz instead of r if you want to create a cuboid search area. For a 3*3*3 box centered at 10,64,10 you would do:

```
/testfor @e[x=9,y=63,z=9,dx=3,dy=3,dz=3,type=Arrow]
```